# Kernel panic not syncing attempting to kill init

Tags: linux-kernel

We have a Citrix Xenserver 6.2 install. Today we had an incident where power to the server was suddenly cut off from the server. It had been running for quite some time without issue. It has quite a large volume in a hardware RAID5. The message we are getting at boot is

```
Scanning and configuring dmraid supported devices
Creating root device.
Mounting root filesystem.
Mount: could not find filesystem '/dev/root'
Setting up other filesystems.
Setting up new root fs
setuproot: moving /dev failed: No such file or directory
no fstab.sys, mounting internal defaults
setuproot: error mounting /proc: No such file or directory
setuproot: error mounting /sys: No such file or directory
Switching to new root and running init.
Unmounting old /dev
Unmounting old /proc
Unmounting old /sys
switchroot: mount failed: No such file or directory
​Kernel panic – not syncing: Attempted to kill init!
​Pid: 1, comm: init Not tainted 2.6.32.43xxxxxxxxxxxxen
```

We've booted into both CentOS5 live cd and Ubuntu live cd. Was able to mount the ext3 file system (/) and see all the logical volumes, BUT not until after running “partprobe” which is curious. When mounted, could browse the ext3 system volume without issue, and see all the LVM volumes for the virtual machines.

The RAID5 array is not broken

Tried booting fallback kernel as well

We rebuilt initrd in /boot when in the live cds, using chroot. They were rebuilt successfully, but subsequent reboots still give a kernel panic with same info as above.

Using gdisk while in a live cd system shows all the GPT partitions are there. There was a warning once about not having a fake msdos partition table, not sure if this was the case previously, or possibly part of the problem?